# Removing from a array and replacing the empty location

Tags: java, arrays

I have to create a public method called `cancelPolicy(int polNum)` which removes the policy from the client's list with the given policy number, if found. It should return true if the policy was found, otherwise it should return false. When a policy is removed from the array, the empty location in the array should be replaced by the last policy in the array. 
The code I have written so far:

```
public int cancelPolicy(int polNum){
    for (int i = 0; i < policies.length; i++) {
        if (policies[i].getPolicyNumber() == polNum) {

        }
    }
    return polNum;
}
```

What I don't understand is how to remove and replace from the array of `policies[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely what you are looking for:

```
public boolean cancelPolicy(int polNum)
{
    int n =  policies.length-1; //optimization by making n = length-1
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { //notice equals in condition 
        if (policies[i].getPolicyNumber() == polNum) {
            policies[i] =   policies[n]; //replace i with last if that's what you meant 
            policies[n] = null; //remove loitering
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to clip the array at the end. It now contains the last element twice (or better: it references the last object twice).

Comment: Got it! I am updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

To replace the found policy, you need to do as follow:

```
public boolean cancelPolicy(int polNum){
    for (int i = 0; i < policies.length; i++) {
        if (policies[i].getPolicyNumber() == polNum) {
            policies[i] = policies[arrSize - 1];
            policies[arrSize - 1] = null;
            arrSize--;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in you class you need to keep the number of policies:

```
private int arrSize;
```

Alternatively you can recreate the array:

```
public boolean cancelPolicy(int polNum){

    for (int i = 0; i < policies.length; i++) {
        if (policies[i].getPolicyNumber() == polNum) {
            int[] newArr = new int[policies.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(policies, 0, newArr , 0, i);
            System.arraycopy(policies, i + 1, newArr, i, policies.length - i - 1);
            policies = newArr;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the best, but not sure if this option is available to you, would be to use a `List` or a `Map`

Answer (score 0):

you cold get the last non null and then set the last element to null as well. this would "replace" it so you don't get duplicated policies.  teachers like it when you think about stuff like that typically

```
public boolean cancelPolicy(int polNum){

for (int i = 0; i < policies.length; i++) {
   if (policies[i].getPolicyNumber() == polNum) {
       for (int j = policies.length - 1; j >=0; j--){
           if (policies[j] != null) {
               policies[i] = policies[j];
               policies[j] = null;
               return true;
           }
       }
   }
}
return false;
}
```